# JSTL: nested <c:if> used to compare two strings not working

Tags: jsp, jstl

In my webapp (based on spring mvc) I have a JSP page whith the follow code:

```
    <c:forEach var="item2" items="${lista_hora}">
<tr>
    <td>
        <c:out value="${item2.hora}"/>
    </td>

    <c:forEach var="item" items="${lista_data}">
    <td>
            <c:set var="isChecked" value="${false}"/>
            <c:forEach var="user" items="${lista_horarios}">
                <c:if test="${item2.hora == user.hora}">
                    <c:if test="${item.data == user.data}">
                        <c:set var="isChecked" value="${true}"/>
                    </c:if>
                </c:if>
            </c:forEach>

            <input type="checkbox" <c:if test="${isChecked}">checked="checked"</c:if> id="cb_001_${item.id}_${item2.id}">

            <script>
                $("#cb_001_${item.id}_${item2.id}").click(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                          url: "cad_horario.html",
                          data: { data: "${item.original}", hora: "${item2.original}" },
                          cache: false
                        }).done(function(data) {
                            $("#result_1").empty().append( data );
                        });
                });
            </script>       
    </td>
    </c:forEach>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

The problem is with the loop above. The page display a matrix where the columns is dates and the rows are a time interval. So, each checkbox are a pair (date, time). The page receives from server three lists: one of dates, one of times,  and other from pairs the user marked in a previous session

What the loop is supossed to do is present the matrix with previous pairs already marked. But this is not happening. Someone can see any wrong in this code?

Comment: ok, i updated the code to include the line where item2 is placed. bt the way, item2 is the list of hours which each pair is made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solve this problem. Happens that onde of the getter methods are returning a wrong value. After change this code, the page works fine. For me, stay the lesson to pay more attention to this details.